# Why the value of the first appended dictionary is changed when a second one is appended?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

In the isolated code snippet below I'm trying to get this result:
*lista_skafwn_to_insert: [{'SERVICE REPORTS': ['1']}, {'SERVICE REPORTS': ['2']}]*,

but instead I get this: *lista_skafwn_to_insert: [{'SERVICE REPORTS': ['2']}, {'SERVICE REPORTS': ['2']}]*.

Why the value of the first dictionary is changed and equals to the value of the last dictionary?

The moment *sr_ged* is 1 I append it to a list. Then the *sxima_skafous* dictionary uses this list as a value in "SERVICE REPORTS" key.

Then I append this dictionary to the *lista_skafwn_to_insert* list.

So the first element of the *lista_skafwn_to_insert* is this *{'SERVICE REPORTS': ['1']}*.

Then I clear *lista_service_reports* and I assign a new value on *sr_ged* and I repeat the above proccess.

Why the value of the first dictionary is affected when it's been appended BEFORE any change occurs in *sr_ged* and *lista_sesrvice_reports*?

Code snippet:

```
lista_skafwn_to_insert = []
lista_service_reports = []

sr_ged = input("sr_ged: ")

lista_service_reports.append(sr_ged)

sxima_skafous = {"SERVICE REPORTS": lista_service_reports}

lista_skafwn_to_insert.append(sxima_skafous)

print('lista_skafwn_to_insert:' + str(lista_skafwn_to_insert))

lista_service_reports.clear()

sr_ged = input("sr_ged: ")

lista_service_reports.append(sr_ged)

sxima_skafous = {"SERVICE REPORTS": lista_service_reports}

lista_skafwn_to_insert.append(sxima_skafous)

print('lista_skafwn_to_insert: ' + str(lista_skafwn_to_insert))
```

Comment: You should definitely look for mutability for Python. Lists are mutable in python, so if, for example: ```a  =[1,2,3]; b = a; b.append(4); print(a)``` >> ```a = [1,2,3,4]``` This should be the same kind of thing you got here. The same is true for a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both dictionaries have a reference to the same list. The `clear` method only mutates the original list. It doesn't create a new one. Change the `clear` call to this:

```
lista_service_reports = []
```

This will start a whole new list to store in the second dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Try using .copy() like this. A list is a pointer, so... that's the point!

```
    lista_skafwn_to_insert = []
    lista_service_reports = []
    
    sr_ged = input("sr_ged: ")
    
    lista_service_reports.append(sr_ged)
    
    sxima_skafous = {"SERVICE REPORTS": lista_service_reports.copy()}
    
    lista_skafwn_to_insert.append(sxima_skafous)
    
    print('lista_skafwn_to_insert:' + str(lista_skafwn_to_insert))
    
    lista_service_reports.clear()
    
    sr_ged = input("sr_ged: ")
    
    lista_service_reports.append(sr_ged)
    
    sxima_skafous = {"SERVICE REPORTS": lista_service_reports.copy()}
    
    lista_skafwn_to_insert.append(sxima_skafous)
    
    print('lista_skafwn_to_insert: ' + str(lista_skafwn_to_insert))
```